# How much did the US spend on each means-tested program during the last 5 years?

Tags: united-states, social-welfare

The [Weekly Standard](http://weeklystandard.com/blogs/report-us-spent-37-trillion-welfare-over-last-5-years_764582.html) had an article that made the following claims:

> **The federal government has spent a total $3.7 trillion on approximately 80 different means-tested poverty and welfare programs.** The common feature of means-tested assistance programs is that they are graduated based on a person’s income and, in contrast to programs like Social Security or Medicare, they are a free benefit and not paid into by the recipient," says the minority side of the Senate Budget Committee.

**What is the breakdown in $US spent on each means-tested program over the last five years?**

Comment: <<Comments removed - please take this all to chat.>>

Comment: @AffableGeek As long as the stack was read before purged; for it covers some of the same ground as the upcoming *meta.politics.se* discussions.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a report [here](http://www.budget.senate.gov/republican/public/index.cfm/files/serve/?File_id=0f87b42d-f182-4b3d-8ae2-fa8ac8a8edad) which has a table called

> Table 2. Spending for Federal Benefits and Services for People with Low Income, by Program (excluding programs for veterans): FY2008-FY2011, including ARRA

I'm not going to reproduce the whole table here, but I'll summarize it.  Each number is total of 2008-2011, including the American Recovery and Reinvestment Act spending, which is tracked separately.

- **Health** - $1,230B <sub>(=$1.23 trillion)</sub>
- **Cash Aid** - $541B
- **Food Assistance** - $332B
- **Education** - $224B
- **Housing & Development** - $198B
- **Social Services** - $157B
- **Employment & Training** - $29B
- **Energy Assistance** - $24B

**Total:** $2,734B <sub>(=$2.734 trillion)</sub>

Note that these numbers are only for four years.  But if you assume the same average spending over five years, you end up with $3,417B <sub>(=$3.417 trillion)</sub>, which is pretty close to the number you're looking for.

Comment: You couldn't find the 5 year report either. Doh! +1 close enough. The nonpartisan [CBO has a report](http://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/attachments/43934-Means-TestedPrograms.pdf) covering the 10 largest programs. Are those numbers consistent?

Comment: No, they're not.  For example, my link has SSI in 2011 being $59B, while your link has it at $49B.  Some of that difference may be inflation, but it's definitely odd.

Comment: the [Office of Manangement and Budget](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2011/assets/budget.pdf), has SSI at $52.7b, so I don't know why the numbers differ so much. Perhaps Fiscal Year to year comparisons?

Comment: @user1873 - Could be.  Economic figures get revised all the time, it's possible these numbers do.  Or it could be inflation. Or slightly differing timeframes (fiscal year vs calendar year).  Or how sub-programs are classified.  *::throws hands in the air::* Who knows?